# Increase Christmas Present Drop Rate

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

Is there a way to increase present drop rate in Simpsons Tapped out Christmas Event? Maybe building more houses or buying area, or anything?

Answer (score 1):

I think not, but what i have, is a lot of friends, and if you visit those friends, you get in total 30 gift cards, or just let some people in your village(like bart or homer) do jobs for gift cards instead of doing jobs for money

Comment: Not a big deal, but the op is asking about _presents_ specifically, not necessarily about gift cards. True, gift cards are the main result of a present... But other presents to drop at friends' towns are also received from presents.

Comment: You get presents when friends visit you. If you visit your friends more often, they will visit your town aswell. But i believe the cristmas event is over(not sure i haven't checked since i bought a windows phone, they dont support this game)

Comment: I don't think you can assume that if you leave presents, your friends will always reciprocate. I mean, they can... But unless they're RL friends, not just random Origin friends, they don't have any incentive to return the favor over giving the presents to any other friend on their account. And with presents, they won't even know who left the presents when elves are used to collect them for example.